# Rails 3 run_callbacks method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm playing around with the new *Rails 3* API and I have a question regarding the new method [run_callbacks(kind, *args, &block)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html#method-i-run_callbacks)

In the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :say_hi
  after_save :say_bye

  private

    def say_hi; puts "hi"; end

    def say_bye; puts "bye"; end

end
```

I can explicit call the *callbacks* on save by running:

```
> u.run_callbacks(:save)
hi
bye
=> true
```

But **my question is**, how I can **only** run the *before_save* or *after_save* callback?

Reviewing the `run_callbacks(kind, *args, &block)` code:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 92
def run_callbacks(kind, *args, &block)
  send("_run_#{kind}_callbacks", *args, &block)
end
```

I don't know how to build `*args` to only call *before* or *after* callbacks, I tried something like `u.run_callbacks(:before_save)` (gives me undefined method error) and `u.run_callbacks(:save, :before)` runs all the *save* callbacks (*before* and *after*).

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are running into a bug in Rails 3.0.  It appears to be in the queue for 3.0.1 as mentioned in [this lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5472-unable-to-manually-run-activerecord-object-callbacks).

As @venables says, you can at least get the before_save callbacks to fire by sending `false` to `run_callbacks(:save)`.

Comment: Yep, It seems like we'r not able to run `before` or `after` save callbacks individually :(, at least in a cleaner way :P.

Comment: @jpemberthy - if you update your question with a specific use case, perhaps we can figure out a workaround that will suffice until the bug is addressed?

Comment: thanks, but that's not necessary, I was just playing with the new API (thanks god) It's not a thing to migrate from 2.3.x or something I'm working on :P

Answer (score 7):

I'm still looking into how to do the after_save only, but to run JUST the before_save callback, you can do something like:

```
u.run_callbacks(:save) { false }
```

This should cancel the callbacks after the before_save ones are run.